# 3 column layout based of Table/Table-cell doesnt work on Chrome and Opera

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, opera

I'm not sure why this wouldn't work on Chrome or Opera. I don't see anything that would be not compatible with other browser.

Any ideas?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3vugadj6/

```
        <style>
            #page_body_table {
                display: table;
                width: 100%;
                vertical-align: center;
            }

            #page_body_left {
                display: table-cell;
                max-width: 100%;
            } 

            #page_body_middle {
                display: table-cell;
                width: 700px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

            #page_body_right {
                display: table-cell;
                max-width: 100%;
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
                #page_body_left, #page_body_right {
                    display: none;
                }
            }
        </style>
        <div>
        <center id="page_body_table">
            <div id="page_body_left">

            </div>
            <div id="page_body_middle">
                this is content of page
            </div>
            <div id="page_body_right">

            </div>
        </center>
    </div>
```

Comment: doesn't work for me in IE or firefox either.  can you provide a picture of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: http://viamarketing.net/dev/index.php 2 side column must be flexible, and disappear at certain width The middle must stay max width of w/e width at that point. Then on like 950px side columns disappear and I want the middle to be responsive and shrink with page width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add: `table-layout: fixed;` to  `#page_body_table` and make it look like this:

```
#page_body_table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: center;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vugadj6/7/).

Exaplanation can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#fixed-table-layout).

Long story short: If the layout is auto, instead of fixed, the width is determined by the content of the cells, which in your case is none, so the middle cell is stretched. If it's fixed it distributes the remaining space to the empty cells.

Comment: I must have the middle column responsive, though. Any way to avoid "fixed" ?

Comment: Disregard my last comment, I'll just remove that tag and replace with "auto on certain width. Thank you much, sir.